# Разница между __getattr__ и __getattribute__

Tags: python, ооп

Я пытаюсь понять, когда использовать `__getattr__`, а когда `__getattribute__`. В [документации](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattribute__#object.__getattribute__) упоминается, что `__getattribute__` применяется к классам нового стиля. Что такое классы нового стиля?

<sub>Перевод вопрос [Difference between __getattr__ vs __getattribute__](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3278077/14227417) от участника [Yarin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165673/yarin)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3278077/14227417

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим на несколько простых примеров использования `__getattr__` и `__getattribute__`.

## __getattr__

Python будет вызывать метод `__getattr__` всякий раз, когда вы запросите атрибут, который еще не был определен. В следующем примере мой класс `Count` не имеет метода `__getattr__`. Теперь в main, когда я пытаюсь получить доступ к атрибутам `obj1.mymin` и `obj1.mymax` все работает нормально. Но когда я пытаюсь получить доступ к атрибуту `obj1.mycurrent` - Python выдает мне

```
AttributeError: 'Count' object has no attribute 'mycurrent'
```

```
class Count():
    def __init__(self,mymin,mymax):
        self.mymin=mymin
        self.mymax=mymax

obj1 = Count(1,10)
print(obj1.mymin)      # 1
print(obj1.mymax)      # 10
print(obj1.mycurrent)  # AttributeError: 'Count' object has no attribute 'mycurrent'
```

Теперь у моего класса `Count` есть метод `__getattr__`. Теперь, когда я пытаюсь получить доступ к `obj1.mycurrent` python возвращает мне все, что я реализовал в своем `__getattr__`. В моем примере каждый раз, когда я пытаюсь вызвать атрибут, которого не существует, python создает этот атрибут и устанавливает ему целочисленное значение 0.

```
class Count:
    def __init__(self,mymin,mymax):
        self.mymin=mymin
        self.mymax=mymax    

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        self.__dict__[item]=0
        return 0

obj1 = Count(1,10)
print(obj1.mymin)       # 1
print(obj1.mymax)       # 10
print(obj1.mycurrent1)  # 0
```

## __getattribute__

Теперь давайте посмотрим на метод `__getattribute__`. Если в вашем классе есть метод `__getattribute__`, python вызывает этот метод для каждого атрибута независимо от того, существует он или нет. Так зачем же нам нужен метод `__getattribute__`? Одна из веских причин заключается в том, что вы можете запретить доступ к атрибутам и сделать их более безопасными, как показано в следующем примере.

Всякий раз, когда кто-то пытается получить доступ к атрибутам, начинающимся с подстроки `'cur'` python вызывает исключение `AttributeError`. В противном случае он возвращает этот атрибут.

```
class Count:

    def __init__(self,mymin,mymax):
        self.mymin=mymin
        self.mymax=mymax
        self.current=None

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item.startswith('cur'):
            raise AttributeError
        return object.__getattribute__(self,item) 
        # либо можете использовать 
        # return super().__getattribute__(item)

obj1 = Count(1,10)
print(obj1.mymin)    # 1
print(obj1.mymax)    # 10
print(obj1.current)  # AttributeError
```

Важно: чтобы избежать бесконечной рекурсии в `__getattribute__`, его реализация всегда должна вызывать метод базового класса с тем же именем для доступа к любым необходимым ему атрибутам. Например:

```
object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

или

```
super().__getattribute__(item)  # и нет self.__dict__[item]
```

Если ваш класс содержит магические методы `__getattr__` и `__getattribute__`, то сначала вызывается `__getattribute__`. Но если `__getattribute__` вызывает исключение `AttributeError`, то исключение будет проигнорировано и будет вызван метод `__getattr__`.

```
class Count(object):

    def __init__(self,mymin,mymax):
        self.mymin=mymin
        self.mymax=mymax
        self.current=None

    def __getattr__(self, item):
            self.__dict__[item]=0
            return 0

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item.startswith('cur'):
            raise AttributeError
        return object.__getattribute__(self,item)
        # или вы можете использовать return super().__getattribute__(item)

obj1 = Count(1,10)
print(obj1.mymin)    # 1
print(obj1.mymax)    # 10
print(obj1.current)  # 0
```

<sub>Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788326/14227417) от участника [N Randhawa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4854721/n-randhawa)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Метод `__getattr__` определяет поведение, когда наш атрибут, который мы пытаемся получить, не найден.
А `__getattribute__` вызывается в любом случае, когда мы обращаемся к какому-либо атрибуту объекта.

```
class Researcher:
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    """
    метод __getattr__ определяет поведение,
    когда наш атрибут, который мы пытаемся получить, не найден
    """
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return 'Nothing found :('
    """
    метод __getattribute__ вызывается в любом случае, когда мы
    обращаемся к какому-либо атрибуту объекта
    """
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'attr':
            return 'nope attr'
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

obj = Researcher("test")

print(obj.attr) --> nope attr
print(obj.what) --> Nothing found :(
print(obj.name) --> test
```