Почему в классе изначально нет метода __getattr__?
Почему в классе изначально нет метода __getattr__ но при этом его можно переопределить?
Например пустой класс
class new_class:
    pass
c = new_class()

Вызов dir(c) не показывает __getattr__ ?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213664/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-getattr-%D0%B8-getattribute

Если коротко, то метода __getattr__ нет у object, так как его функцию выполняет метод __getattribute__, а перегрузка __getattr__ позволяет изменить поведение при исключении.

Как можно переопределить то чего нет?

Ну хорошо, не переопределить, а просто определить. Просто в Питоне есть соглашение, что в таких-то случаях вызываются такие-то методы объекта (если они описаны). Это вот как-раз такой случай. Если вы опишете в вашем классе этот метод, то Питон его будет дёргать при выполнении некоторых условий.

Вообще ситуация "таких методов сейчас у класса нет, но если вы их опишете, то они будут использоваться" довольно типическая в Питоне. В отличие от других языков, где такие методы регулируются интерфейсами, которые реализует данный класс или ещё какими-то контрактами, в Питоне это просто описано в документации, что вот в таких-то случаях будут использоваться такие-то методы. А если их нет, то будут использоваться другие вместо них. И тоже описано в документации - какие. Или никакие не будут использоваться, если и тех нет.
